# Trouble invoking a JS function via jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on some legacy code in javascript and I have a problem I can't work out.

When the document first loads, a JS function named `addDecisionStateDetailsFields()` gets invoked. This method generates HTML which it appends to a certain `div`. The `Ctrl C, Ctrl V` version is at [pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/5ms3En6H)

So when a document first loads, I get the required HTML. But in another case I have to call that same function via AJAX and I did something like:

```
function editSPDecision(decision){
    $('#serviceProcedureAddDecision').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: { 'decisionId': decision.id, 'authorizationId': ${authorizationId} },
        url:'../editDecision/${id}',
        success: function(data,textStatus) {
            jQuery('#serviceProcedureEditDecision').html(data);
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus) {
            attachDatePickerClasses();
            addDecisionStateDetailsFields("spDecision_approve", "approveDiv", "Approve", "${ReviewerApproveReason.getValueCommaSeperated()}", "${ReviewerApproveReason.getNameCommaSeperated()}");
        }
    });
}
```

Here, I've invoked the method `addDecisionStateDetailsFields()` with the right params. But after the AJAX call completes, I can't get the generated HTML appended to the HTML of the page.

To cross check, I put an `alert` inside the method and after the AJAX call completes the method in fact gets invoked, only that the generated HTML is not appended to the `div`. Is there ssomething that I'm missing here?

Comment: Is the `success` callback actually getting called?

Comment: @iUngi I alerted the `generatedStr` and using Firebug I inserted the generated HTML to the div where it should have been and voila it fits flawlessly. But can't get that same thing happen after a normal ajax call. I doubt sth. is wrong with the .append() here but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the addDecisionStateDetailsFields right before

```
$('#' + masterParentDiv).append(generatedStr);
```

can you do

```
alert($('#' + masterParentDiv).length);
```

That will tell you whether the masterParentDiv is found, if its found you should get back something other than 0.

Not 100% sure about that I am going to say but, change

```
$('#' + masterParentDiv).append(generatedStr);
```

to

```
jQuery('#' + masterParentDiv).append(generatedStr);
```

Comment: Where do you see any reference to a `this` keyword that could possibly necessitate this? Also, you probably meant `scope.attach...` and `scope.addDecision...`.

Comment: @Jose Vega But as I mentioned already, those functions in fact get invoked. I can even get a alert after the ajax call.

Comment: The OP is calling attachDatePickerClasses and addDecisionStateDetailsFields from inside the complete callback. He needs to add scope to that calls of those functions.

Comment: @rstarter An alert after Ajax wouldn't tell you if you invoked the function addDecisionStateDetailsFields, an alert inside addDecisionStateDetailsFields would tell you that...Another thing I noticed you have a display:none, does that matter, do you need to change it back afterwards?

Comment: @Jose Vega Sorry for the language...I meant sth. else and wrote sth. else...(c not a native speaker)....I actually put an alert inside the method like `alert(generatedStr)` and whatever was genereated and alerted, I copied and pasted using Firebug to div where the generated HTML should have been...and it works. I simply can't have it done in a normal way. But I really appreciate your efforts to help a noob...can u elaborate what you mean by adding scope to the call. And BTW, I need that `display:none` which I may need to change dynamically later on.

Comment: I made some other suggestions in my answer

Comment: @Jose Vega Yes the alert gave a value of 1